# Why does Wubi installer not find my CD and then abort?

Tags: 11.10, installation, wubi, log

When I try to install Ubuntu 11.10 using Wubi I get an error asking to check

> C:/users/home/appdata/local/temp/wubi-11.10-rev245.log

I don't know what to do.

I am not using the internet to install Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu in `.iso` format and I install it by keeping Wubi and the `.iso` file in the same folder.

Here is [the log file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1030956/).

Comment: The log indicates that Wubi couldn't find an Ubuntu CD in any drive or an ISO...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the MD5 sum of the ISO file of Ubuntu? Check it once.

If it's the same as the file you downloaded, then try to make a bootable ISO using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Then, boot from USB. Click the "Try Ubuntu" option during booting.

If everything works, then you can try with Wubi. Wubi works on NTFS, so check the partition. If you want GRUB as boot loader you can install it from the "Try Ubuntu" window only.

I would recommend not to install in "Try Ubuntu" if you are not familiar with Ubuntu though. There may be dependencies of the Windows boot loader for a few systems. So, as I already said, if the "Try Ubuntu" method through the ISO works, then you can test with Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO is bad:

```
06-08 23:19 DEBUG Distro: checking Ubuntu ISO C:\Ubuntu Setup\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
06-08 23:19 DEBUG Distro: does not contain casper\filesystem.squashfs
```

So wubi tries to download the diskimage (but it fails since you're offline):

```
06-08 23:22 DEBUG downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-wubi-amd64.tar.xz > C:\ubuntu\disks\ubuntu-11.10-wubi-amd64.tar.xz
06-08 23:22 ERROR TaskList: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (7, ‘getaddrinfo failed’)>
```

So download the ISO again. Wubi will check it and tell you if it fails. It's best to MD5 check it yourself if you're offline (as Wubi bypasses the md5 check in this case). Or run it online if possible because it only needs to download a small metalink file to check the MD5 sum.